# Does setting a random state in sklearn's RandomForestClassifier bias your model?

Tags: random, scikit-learn, random-forest, random-seed

I've training a random forest model and am using a consistent `random_state` value. I'm also getting really good accuracies across my training, test, and validation datasets (all are around ~.98). Though the minority class comprises only ~10% of the dataset.

Here's some code if you're interested:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True, random_state=310, n_estimators=300)
model.fit(subset, train.iloc[:,-1])
```

Given the good accuracy scores across training, validation and testing datsets, does `random_state` affect the generalization of my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random_state` does not affect the generalization of the model. In fact, it is the best practice to have same value for `random_state` when you tune your hyper parameters such as `n_estimators`, `depth`, etc. This will ensure that your performance is not affected by the random initial state.

Also, Accuracy is not the recommended metrics to measure the performance of the model, when you have such as unbalanced dataset.

Area under the ROC or PR curve could be one of the few best things you can use but there are a lot of metrics available. See [here](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.metrics.classification_report_imbalanced.html)

Comment: Thanks! just what I was looking for. re accuracy - I'm actually using a confusion matrix to measure for internal metrics, but that is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

> random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)
>
> If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random.

In general `random_state` is be used to set the internal parameters initially, so you can repeat the training deterministically. Now you can change other hyperparameters (e.g. number of trees) to compare the results.

A disadvantage could be that you don't find the global optimum. But your results sound really good with an accuracy of `0.98`.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem of learning an optimal decision tree is known to be NP-complete under several aspects of optimality and even for simple concepts. Consequently, practical decision-tree learning algorithms are based on heuristic algorithms such as the greedy algorithm where locally optimal decisions are made at each node. Such algorithms cannot guarantee to return the globally optimal decision tree. This can be mitigated by training multiple trees in an ensemble learner, where the features and samples are randomly sampled with replacement.

random_state is for random selections of sub-features, smaller than the total features, and sub-samples. This parameter controls random choices.